# Different file process in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive, bigdata, elastic-map-reduce

I have installed Hadoop and hive. I can process and query over xls, tsv files using hive. I want to process other files such as docx, pdf, ppt. how can i do this? Is there any separate procedure to process these files in AWS? please help me.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any difference in consuming those files as in any Hadoop platform. For easy access and durable storage - you may put those files in S3.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I want to know how can i run query over docx, pdf, ppt files.

Comment: I believe, There are open source APIs to interact / extract data from all of the above mentioned files. You would use it in conjunction with the Hadoop / EMR